# Virtual Bridges do not seem to be carrying LLDP information

Tags: routing, juniper, juniper-junos, virtual

Network community,

I am testing a Juniper virtual-SRX (D.70).  When configured on a desktop the vSRX works wonderfully (fully functional/connected OSPF router), however when I plug it into the rest of the network, it is not able to retrieve any LLDP information.  (Note: In this instance, there were no virtual bridges)

*Configuration using virtual-bridge*

When the links were configured using virtual bridges, the vSRX could see all of its *virtual LLDP neighbors, but again, could not see out to the rest of the network.

When I connect to a *physical* Juniper/Cisco router, they are of course able to see the network, but are not able to see the directly connected vSRX.

- All ports are set to promiscuous mode as specified by Juniper for installation
- All firewall/security functionality was deleted and flow status is set to "packet-based"

Any help would be appreciated.  I have a feeling it has to do with the virtual bridge configuration.  Will follow up once I have a solution.

Thank you again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you just need to make a few changes:

edit -->  /etc/sysctl.conf

Set all the: net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-(ip6,ip,arptables) = 0

Then make sure to address the "linux bridges silently drop LLDP messages"

Great example found here:  https://thenetworkway.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/lldp-traffic-and-linux-bridges/

Note: Also enabled spanning tree, although I have yet to confirm if that truly makes a difference.